# Express the solutions of the equation $Ax = 0$ as a linear combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Express the solutions of the equation Ax = 0 as a linear combination of vectors where A is $$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr2&1&-3\cr}$$

The answer I get after doing Gauss reduction is:

$
$$\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr z}$ =$\pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0}$+b $\pmatrix{1\cr -2\cr 0}$

Is my answer correct? If not, where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes, Gauss reduction is one way to go. You have already set up the start by writing down the matrix. Now, do the Gauss reduction.

Comment: You read your book, it's bound to have some explanations that can help. And if you still can't figure it out, you come back, and add your own work to the question, so we can help you understand the part that's cauing you trouble.

Comment: Are you talking about the augmented matrix?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You should post your steps to figure out where were you mistaken

Comment: You have had a couple of answers now. Are you ready to accept one of them, User? or do you still have a question about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We have the equations $$x+2y+3z=0$$ and $$2x+y-3z=0$$

Now, choose $z$ arbitarily, but NOT $0$, for example $z=1$. Now, you can easily solve the equation system. The solution is $x=3$ and $y=-3$. So, the general solution is $$t\pmatrix{3\\-3\\1}$$ with $t\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the equations which gives $3x+3y=0$ implying $x=-y$ , choose $y$ arbitarily, but not $0$, for example $y=1$ to get $x=-1$ and $z=-\frac{1}{3}$ Multiplying with $3$, you get the vector $(-3,3,-1)$. Note that $$t\pmatrix{-3\\3\\-1}$$ is the same result as $$t\pmatrix{3\\-3\\1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr2&1&-3\cr}.\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}\iff\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l} x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0\\2x_1+x_2-3x_3=0 \end{array}\right. \quad \dots $
$$\dots\implies \mathcal{S}=\bigg\{(3\lambda,-3\lambda,\lambda),\quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\bigg\}$$